# Automapper cannot fill the properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, automapper

I use Automapper in an MVC project where I also use ASP.NET Identity and inherit from ApplicationUser class to my custom user tables: Student and Coordinator. The problem is that; I retrieve User data and there is filled custom property in it (called Number), but after applying the Automappe's mapping, it only fills the properties in ApplicationUser and the Number property is null. Is there any mistake or how to fix it?

**Domain Models:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; } 

    //code omitted for brevity
}

public class Student: ApplicationUser
{     
    public int? Number { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     

    public int? Number { get; set; }

    //code omitted for brevity
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public  ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    ApplicationUser user = db.Users.Find(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, RegisterViewModel>();
    });

    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    //var source = new ApplicationUser();
    var dest = mapper.Map<ApplicationUser, RegisterViewModel>(user);

    return PartialView("_Details", dest);
}
```

Comment: One other thing - you should NOT configure AutoMapper on every single controller action. AutoMapper config is just like EF config - static and defined once per AppDomain. You should have a Mapper.Initialize in your global.asax or similar and initialize your maps once.

Comment: @JimmyBogard Thanks for reply. **1)** Could you please post an example as answer? **2)** I need to convert the ApplicationUser to RegisterViewModel in Controller, in that case, is there any approach to solve this? Could you please reply?

Comment: Can you show us RegisterViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect it to map `Number`. You're talking about two different types. If `db.Users.Find(id);` is an `ApplicationUser` then it won't work like you're showing because `ApplicationUser` does not have a `Number` property.

If the object returned from `db.Users.Find(id);` is really a `Student`. Then `cast` it and do the mapping from `Student`

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Student, RegisterViewModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
});

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var myAppUser = new ApplicationUser();
var student = myAppUser as Student;
var appUserResult = Mapper.Map<RegisterViewModel>(student);
```

Comment: You analysed the problem and proposed a good solution. For those who encounter the same problem **.ForMember(dest => dest.Xxx, opt => opt.Ignore()** lines should also be added for all of the other custom properties. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Dont map "AppicationUser" map student like so:

```
var dest = mapper.Map<Student, RegisterViewModel>(user);
```

Also change the map in the configure:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Student, RegisterViewModel>();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: But user thanks, but user is AppicationUser type and boxing does not solve the problem.